# boost DFS does not work with setS vertice lists

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, boost-property-map

The following code is not compiled.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::setS, // outedge list
    boost::setS, // vertex list
    boost::directedS, // undirected 
    boost::no_property, // vertex prop
    boost::no_property, // edge prop
    boost::no_property, // graph prop
    boost::setS // edgelist
> Graph;

bool hasCycle(const Graph& aG) 
{
    try {
        boost::topological_sort(
            aG, 
            boost::make_function_output_iterator([](int){}));
    } catch(boost::not_a_dag const&)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

It works after changing vertice lists to be vecS
     http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abeb9e3f96e92af0

Is this limitation because DFS needs a deterministic visits?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "limitation" is documented as the need for a vertex index. You could add one (note that you also should replace `int` by `Graph::vertex_descriptor`), or adjust the graph type to include one:

## Adding an external index property map

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed86e473a1180bea)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::setS, // outedge list
    boost::setS, // vertex list
    boost::directedS, // undirected 
    boost::no_property, // vertex prop
    boost::no_property, // edge prop
    boost::no_property, // graph prop
    boost::setS // edgelist
> Graph;

bool hasCycle(const Graph& aG)
{
    try {
        std::map<Graph::vertex_descriptor, size_t> index;
        auto pmap = boost::make_assoc_property_map(index);

        for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::vertices(aG)))
            index[vd] = index.size();

        boost::topological_sort(
            aG,
            boost::make_function_output_iterator([](Graph::vertex_descriptor){}),
            boost::vertex_index_map(pmap));
    }
    catch (boost::not_a_dag const&)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
}
```

## Adding an internal index property map

This amounts to shifting the burden to the caller. This might make (a lot of) sense depending on the performance requirements for you application.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/458ee2c71630212b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::setS, // outedge list
    boost::setS, // vertex list
    boost::directedS, // undirected 
    boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int>, // vertex prop
    boost::no_property, // edge prop
    boost::no_property, // graph prop
    boost::setS // edgelist
> Graph;

bool hasCycle(const Graph& aG)
{
    try {
        boost::topological_sort(
            aG,
            boost::make_function_output_iterator([](Graph::vertex_descriptor){})
        );
    }
    catch (boost::not_a_dag const&)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::mt19937 prng{ std::random_device{}() };
    Graph g;
    boost::generate_random_graph(g, 100, 200, prng);
    auto index = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g);

    int gen_id = 0;
    for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::vertices(g))) {
        boost::put(index, vd, gen_id++);
        std::cout << "Vertex " << boost::get(index, vd) << "\n";
    }

    bool check = hasCycle(g);
}
```